# OTC Derivatives Moneyness Conventions

Tags: options

When looking at the OTC Derivatives market, is there a standard moneyness convention that is applied? And if so, what is that bucketed approach? For example: 90%-110% for ATM, 70%-90%, 110%-130%, etc... Is there asset class considerations that would change the band structure?

Is this data useful enough with understanding the activity on the vol surface as a proxy data source?

Comment: In the FX markets, yes. Please google fx otc options conventions.

Comment: Not aware of the conventions for the zones/buckets though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any actual formal convention, generally though within +- 1 standard deviation of returns (over the time period to expiry) would be ATM.